# DTO to entity conversion: in service or controller, for manytoone owning side, should service accept DTO

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, design-patterns, architecture

Suppose I have a simple application with entities like these:

**Dog.java**:

```
@Entity(name = "dogs")
public class Dog  {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "dog_sequence",
                            sequenceName = "dog_sequence",
                            allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
                            generator = "dog_sequence")
    private Long id;
  
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;

    // getters, setters, constructors
}
```

**Command.java**:

```
@Entity(name = "commands")
public class Command  {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "command_sequence",
                            sequenceName = "command_sequence",
                            allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
                            generator = "command_sequence")
    private Long id;
  
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "dog_id", nullable = false)
    private Dog dog;

    // getters, setters, constructors
}
```

So a dog can know several commands, and each command is unique for a dog (belongs only to one dog).

I have a view (website page) that allows the admin to add new commands to each dog and also change the dog's name.

Once done, the view would send a `POST` request to `/api/dog/edit` with JSON like this:

```
{
  "commands": ["some command name", "another command name"],
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Updated Dog Name"
}
```

Now, because the `Dog` entity doesn't contain a `List<Command>` field, the controller can't map all of the JSON to the `Dog` entity, so I created a `DogDto`:

**DogDto.java**:

```
public class DogDto  {
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  private List<CommandDto> commands;  
  

  // getters, setters, constructors
}
```

and `CommandDto`:

**CommandDto.java**:

```
public class CommandDto  {
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  private DogDto dog;

  // getters, setters, constructors
}
```

Now my controller can map the JSON passed from view to the `DogDto`:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "api/dog")
public class DogController {
    ...

    @PostMapping("edit")
    @CrossOrigin
    public ResponseEntity<DogDto> editDog(@RequestBody DogDto dogDto)  {
      ...
      Dog dog = mapper.map(dogDto, Dog.class);
      List<Command> commands = new ArrayList<>();
      for (CommandDto commandDto: dogDto.getCommands())  {
        Command command = mapper.map(commandDto, Command.class);
        commands.add(command);
      }
      ...
    }
}
```

Now I can map the `DogDto` to a `Dog` and `Command` entities. But what would be the best way to persist them? Currently my `DogService` has a

```
public boolean editDog(Dog dog) {...}
```

method that accepts a dog, tries to find it by ID:

```
Dog foundDog = this.dogRepository.findById(dog.getId());
```

and if the dog was found, update its name field and do `this.dogRepository.save(foundDog);`.

However I also need to save the commands. The `Dog` entity doesn't contain the list of commands. So I either need to change the `editDog` method signature to `boolean editDog(DogDto dog)` or do it in the controller like this:

```
for (Command command: commands)  {
  command.setDog(dogFoundById);
  this.commandService.createCommand(command);
}
```

I'm lost as to what to do here.

And I've also been wondering what if I had a more complex structure, with more nested entities:

```
public class A  {
  ...
  @OneToMany
  private List<B> bs;
}
```

```
public class C  {
  ...
  @ManyToOne
  private B b;
}
```

would the best design decision be different?

Comment: Is there a specific reason for not having a collection of commands in your dog entity?
It would makes sense I think to declare a \@OneToMany List<Command> commands; in Dog. You could also check out the javax.persistance @ElementCollection annotation in my opinion, it might be a good tool for your problem.

Comment: @Csisanyi I spent a lot of time reading through tutorials, and many seem to claim that it's better to have a unidirectional `@ManyToOne`. After reading the pitfalls of bidirectional relationships (eg the need to keep them synchronized) I don't feel advanced enough to weather that. For instance, at the start of this tutorial https://www.bezkoder.com/jpa-one-to-many/ they say it's best to use unidirectional `@ManyToOne`. This example is a simplified version of my bigger project, in which the `Command` class has more fields, so I'm not sure `@ElementCollection` would work for me

Answer (score 2):

In this request : **/api/dog/edit**

> So a dog can know several commands, and each command is unique for a dog (belongs only to one dog).
> I have a view (website page) that allows the admin to add new commands to each dog and also change the dog's name.

**First**, we can analyse this business needs.

It should be able to be split into two operations: **Edit dog** , **Save many commands**

analyse for these operations:

1. When we edit dog info, we should not know which command is related to it.(for dog entity)
2. But , when we save command, we must be know its relationship to the dog.(for command entity)

1 and 2 on service:

```
// (for normal conditions it should be judge name not null)
// SQL like this : UPDATE dog SET name = 'xxx' WHERE dog_id = int
int/boolean editDogName(Dog dog);

// normal SQL, judge CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(commands)
int/boolean saveCommands(List<Command> commands);
```

**Second**, we should build a top model to support this operation/needs.

```
public class EditDogDTO{

     @NotNull(message = "id cannot be null")
     private Long id;
     
     private String name;
     
     private List<String> commands;

     public Dog getDogEntity(){
            // .....
            return mapper.map(this, Dog.class);
     }
    
     public List<Command> getCommandEntities(Dog dog){
    
            if(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(commands)){
                   List<Command> result = new ArrayList<>();
                   for(String s : commands){
                         result.add(new Command(null, s, dog);
                   }
                   return result;
            }
            return Collections.EmptyList();
     }
}
```

**Finally**, we should splice these business logic.

[First answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76405027/22020873) and [Second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76398850/22020873) is right, all architecture should be follow [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) .

Controller layer should focus on check and wrap return value.So we can create another layout to splice business logic(provider, support....)

```
@Service
public class DogProvider{

       @Transactional(....)
       public boolean editDogInfo(EditDogDTO editDTO){

             Dog dog = editDTO.getDogEntity();
             // judge is success
             if(dogService.editDog(dog).....) return false;
             // 
             commandService.saveCommands(editDTO.getCommandEntities(dog));

             return false;
       }
}
```

---

```
@Controller
public class DogProvider{

    @PostMapping("edit")
    @CrossOrigin
    public ResponseEntity<boolean> editDog(@RequestBody @Valid EditDogDTO editDogDTO)  {

         return ResponseEntity
                           .ok(dogProvider.editDogInfo(editDogDTO))
                           .build();
    }
}
```

Hope my answer can help you.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to make use of business objects.

We always want to have the freedom to change domain objects without it impacting our view objects. This means that the domain entities can evolve as the business needs begin to change without altering consumers of your API.

The constraint here is that the controllers always exchange DTOs with clients of your API and your repository calls are always handling domain objects. When performing business logic on objects, you usually don't want to choose one over the other. Either choice feels inappropriate.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you saying that a new layer should be introduced? `DogDto` in controller, `Dog` in repository, and `DogBusiness` in service - `editDog(DogBusiness dogBusiness)`? How would a `DogBusiness` differ from `DogDto` in this example then?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you use MVC pattern here. If yes, then I would prefer the following choice:

```
boolean editDog(DogDto dog)
```

because no logic should be placed in controller. Besause:

- all cohesive logic should be placed in one place. Better to support this code
- simpler to write tests for controller and logic layer
- because of [separation of concerns](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/32581/how-do-you-explain-separation-of-concerns-to-others) and the Single Responsibility Principle of [SOLID](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/155852/programming-solid-principles). Controller ought to handle requests and nothing more, business layer should have business logic, database layer should contain only code which interacts with database without any logic